# ImportError: cannot import name 'ajax'

Tags: python, django

using python 3.4, django 1.9.7 ,django_ajax 0.2.0 ;
and test in python 2.7 too ;
Here is my code :

```
from django_ajax.decorators import ajax
from models import Product
from cart.cart import Cart

@ajax
def ajax_add_to_cart(request):
    if 'product_id' in request.GET and request.GET['product_id']:

        product_id = request.GET['product_id']

        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        cart = Cart(request)
        cart.add(product, product.price, quantity=1)
        items_in_cart = cart.itemCount()

        return {'items_in_cart': items_in_cart}
```

I get this error :

```
from django_ajax.decorators import ajax
ImportError: cannot import name 'ajax'
```

Tnx for help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you add 'django_ajax' into the INSTALLED_APPS list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've apparently installed the wrong package due to name similarity with another package. That usually happens.

You've installed [`django_ajax 0.2.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_ajax/0.2.0) while you intend to use [`djangoajax`](https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax) which has the `ajax` decorator. The former does not have or use decorators.

Remove `django_ajax` with:

```
pip uninstall django_ajax
```

---

Then install `djangoajax` which is usually imported as `django_ajax` and would be added as `django_ajax` to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
pip install djangoajax
```

Your import would no longer raise an error:

```
>>> from django_ajax.decorators import ajax
>>>
```